# SAS program to check file level controls on multiple files

Tags: sql, sas, sas-macro, proc-sql, enterprise-guide

This code is working perfectly when we pass single file but I need to achieve the same when I pass multiple files. If any file fails any macro condition it should be logged in the `error.csv`.

Here I do have 2 macros, whenever I pass a file it should go through the 2 macros and if encounters any issues it should write the error msg in the `errorlog.csv`.

**Macro 1:** `get_FileExtension` - used to check whether the file which is passed have valid extensions(TXT, TTX, SAS7BDAT, CSV). IF the passed file has no valid extension it writes log in `errorlog.csv` ("Invalid file extension for file &file")

**Macro 2:** `check_file_exists` - used to check whether the file which is passed is on the server. IF the passed file is not on the server it writes log in `errorlog.csv` ("The file &filepath does not exist on the server")

```
%macro get_FileExtension(file, path);
    %local extension logtext;
    %let extension = %upcase(%sysfunc(scan(&file.,-1,.)));
    
    %if &extension. = TXT or &extension. = TTX %then %let extension='09'x;
    %else %if &extension. = CSV %then %let extension='CSV';
    %else %if &extension. = SAS7BDAT %then %let extension='SAS';
    %else %do;
        %let logtext = ERROR: Invalid file extension for file &file.;
        %put &logtext;
        %global error_message;
        %let error_message = &logtext;
        data null;
            file errorlog mod;
            /* Check if headers have been written */
            if n = 1 then put "Date Time Message";
            put "&sysdate9. &sysampm. &logtext";
        run;
        %let extension='UNKNOWN';
    %end;
    
    &extension.
%mend get_FileExtension;

%macro check_file_exists(filepath);
    %local logtext;
    %if %sysfunc(fileexist(&filepath.)) %then %do;
        %let logtext = NOTE: The file &filepath exists on the server.;
        %put &logtext;
    %end;
    %else %do;
        %let logtext = ERROR: The file &filepath does not exist on the server.;
        %put &logtext;
        %global error_message;
        %let error_message = &error_message. %str( ) &logtext;
        data null;
            
            /* Check if headers have been written */
            if n = 1 then put "Date Time Message";
            put "&sysdate9. &sysampm. &logtext";
        run;
    %end;
%mend check_file_exists;

%macro check_and_get_FileExtension(file, path);
    %local extension;
    %let extension = %get_FileExtension(&file, &path);
    %check_file_exists(&file);
    %put NOTE: File Extension is &extension.;
    %put &error_message.;
    data null;
        file "//home/ketha/errorlog.csv" mod;
        length message $200; /* Adjust the length as per your requirement */
        message = catx(' ', "&sysdate9.", "&sysampm.", "&error_message.");
        put message;
    run;
%mend check_and_get_FileExtension;

%let file=/home/ketha/eoth_bshg.invalidext;
%let path=/home/ketha;
%check_and_get_FileExtension(&file., &path.);
```

Output for invalid file:

```
ERROR: Invalid file extension for file /home/ketha/eoth_bshg.invalidext
ERROR: The file /home/ketha/eoth_bshg.invalidext does not exist on the server.
```

I tried the same above for multiple files but it is failing. I need help to achieve the same on multiple files.

Comment: I would start by getting these macros to work if you call `%check_and_get_FileExtension(&file., &path.)` three times in a row to check three different files: one that does exist; one that doesn't exist; and one that does exist. It looks like declaring the macro variable ERROR_MESSAGE as a global macro variable will be a problem.  You might be better off making it local to check_and_get_FileExtension.

Comment: Are you asking for help in planning how to write a macro that will take in a list a values?  Or do you also need help with formatting the output file with the messages?  Your code seems to be trying to write a delimited file, but your comment says you just want ordinary ERROR: message lines.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a list of values then pick a delimiter to use, hopefully something that cannot appear in one of the values.  | is a good choice for filenames since it cannot be part of the filename.

```
 %macro check(filelist,path);
   %local i file ext exists ;
   %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&filelist,|));
     %let file=%qscan(&filelist,&i,|);
     %if not %index(&file,.) %then %let ext=;
     %else %let ext=%qscan(&file,-1,.);
     %let exist=%sysfunc(fileexist(&path.&file));
%* Now do something with the derived information ;
     %put &=i &=exist &=ext &=file ;

   %end;
%mend;
```

Example call:

```
1    %check(filelist=bar.txt|class.xlsx|class.sas7bdat|junk|junk.junk,path=c:\downloads\);
I=1 EXIST=1 EXT=txt FILE=bar.txt
I=2 EXIST=1 EXT=xlsx FILE=class.xlsx
I=3 EXIST=1 EXT=sas7bdat FILE=class.sas7bdat
I=4 EXIST=0 EXT= FILE=junk
I=5 EXIST=0 EXT=junk FILE=junk.junk
```

Answer (score 0):

A lazy but efficient approach would be to write another macro to iterate over your list of paths/files. Of note, you'll want to take care how they are delimited (e.g. can your files/paths contain spaces?). A simple example:

```
%macro multi_check_and_get(files, paths, delim = @);
   %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&files, &delim));
      %check_and_get_FileExtension(%scan(&files, &i, &delim), %scan(&paths, &i, &delim));
   %end;
%mend;
```

There is a *lot* I would extend here, for example the code assumes that `files` and `paths` contain an equal number of `delim`-delimited values, there's zero consideration for macro quoting, this will do nothing if `files` is blank, etc.